# JS Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have python flask application and I getting error. I searched all of the questions which have same header with my question and I could not find answer.

From flask I return res, paths and imgPut

## Python

```
app.route("/getTheValues", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def detectionAnalysis():
    ...
...



        return render_template("detection.html", res=acc5,imgPut=str(name),
                                   methos=json.dumps(methos) )
```

## HTML JS

```
var array = {{res}}
var classes = {{methos| safe}}
var path2 = {{imgPut}}
```

I can take res and classes however I cannot take the imgPut. It gives error. From flast to js I can the value of imgPut but it gives Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : error.

It takes the value. This from developer tools

```
var path2 = C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\images\posterler-uzum-yapragi.jpg
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `{{xyz}}` things need to be in quotes if they're being interpolated into JavaScript.

Comment: `var path2 = C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\images\posterler-uzum-yapragi.jpg` this is not a valid string and it's not a valid identifier, nor valid other syntax. As mentioned, you likely need to surround this value in quotes.

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\images\posterler-uzum-yapragi.jpg this comes from flask, how can ı surrounds this ?

Comment: `var path2 = "{{imgPut}}"`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.